# Android sdk 14 emulator appears but on tests No connected device

Tags: android, jenkins, sdk, android-emulator

Hi in Jenkins android emulator plugin i set up emulator with the following properties:

```
Android OS version -14
Screen density - 320
Screen resolution - 1280x720
Device locale en_US
SD card size 100M
Target ABI armeabi-v7a
```

Job starts good, if i login in vm via vnc i can see that emulator appears, all my gradle preparations tasks are good, but when tests started, emulator immediately shut down and tests failed with Error: No connected devices!

piece of my log:

```
[LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:connectedAndroidTest
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:connectedAndroidTest'
13:37:59 13:38:00.119 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] >  com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No connected devices!
```

All android sdks from 15 version till 21 is ok, trouble only with 14th version.

Really don't know to do

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I am currently stuck at the same!

Comment: In my case, i able to run the Jenkins Build. But sequence time not working any more showing this error :
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!